# Rails Unable to configure simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, simple-form

I'm trying to start a new rails app with devise and simple_form. 
After adding the simple_form gem to my gemfile and bundling, when I try to configure simple_form by running `rails generate simple_form:install` from the command line I get the following error:

```
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get': uninitialized constant View (NameError)
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the it's just a warning.

The underlying error is: `~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in`const_get': uninitialized constant View (NameError)`

Is `View` one of your devise models? If yes, does it exist?

Try running:

`rails generate devise View`